# AJAX result is gone when print the page

Tags: ajax, web, flask, printing

when I try to print the page, some data are gone as you can see from the below examples.

All data that are missing is retrieved by AJAX method.

I believe this is because web browser calls the page again when window.print() method is called and render earlier than ajax is called.

Because every now and then the data shows, but not always.

How can I make sure that print preview is rendered after every ajax method in DOM is called?

*update

This is the server part. When a user requests "/evaluation/silver/userinfo" url, **my.html** will be rendered and ajax is called in **my.html** where the ajax code is located.

```
from models.restful_api import *
api.add_resource(UserInfo, "/evaluation/silver/userinfo")

@app.route('/my/page')
def SilverEvaluation_new():
    return render_template('folder/my.html')
```

And below is the ajax function that calls API.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/evaluation/silver/userinfo",
        data: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
            var name, user_birth, bodycheck_date, gender, score, how_many;
            name = JSON.parse(data).name;
            user_birth = JSON.parse(data).birth;
            bodycheck_date = JSON.parse(data).check_date;
            gender = JSON.parse(data).gender;
            if (gender === "M"){
                gender = "남"
            } else {
                gender = "여"
            }
            score = JSON.parse(data).score;
            how_many = JSON.parse(data).how_many;

            $("#user_name").text(name);
            $("#user_birth").text(user_birth);
            $("#bodycheck_date").text(bodycheck_date);
            $("#user_gender").text(gender);
            $("#bodycheck_score").text(parseInt(score/6));
            $(".bodycheck_score").text(parseInt(score/6));
            $("#how_many").text(how_many);
        }
    })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Share code where you call ajax request and how you render that particular page in flask

Comment: @DinkoPehar I added the code, let me know if my code is lacking something

Comment: Are you sure that is being executed ? Everything seems fine. You use id's of elements and insert them with text method. Make sure that ajax request is below rendered html. Also print `data` to see if it's being fetched.

Comment: @DinkoPehar I found something funny, when I try to print via javascript window.print() method, the symptom is just the same as my question. But when I press Ctrl+P on web, every result is rendered just fine! 
What is the difference between those two?

Comment: Then you call it too early. put windows.print() after last line in success, or call it after some time with setTimeout() function.